# how do I create a breadcrumb to work with multiple custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, plugin-recommendation, breadcrumb

I have created several custom post types, and custom taxonomies to manage my large art portfolio. All of this is working very well. There is a post type for "art" and "design" as well as custom taxonomies for stuff like "color"

I want to add breadcrumbs that will show the taxonomy the user clicked on to arrive at a particular image. For example:

from the `achive-art.php` someone clicks on the custom taxonomy "color" and then the classification of purple they are taken to a `taxonomy-color.php` page that lists the results. When they click a thumbnail to see the full post I would like to see a breadcrumb that reads:

art  > purple > title of the post

I've tried a ton of plug-ins but they only work with one taxonomy or will show:

art > title of the post.

I'm still kind of new to wordpress and trying to wrap my head around everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way you can remember which taxonomy the user arrived through to a certain post is by storing it in a cookie. This is essentially what the [Smarter Navigation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smarter-navigation/) plugin does, except it can handle all archives, not just taxonomy archives.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! this plug in does what I wanted originally, but I couldn't find a way to do it so I thought I'd have to settle for breadcrumbs. I understand the concept of storing as  cookie but an too new to programing to actually do it. But again, I like this sooooo much better. Thanks!